# angular 4 Currency pipe don't format numbers correctly

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am using a currency pipe to display the € correct format:

```
{{value | currency:'EUR':true}}
```

I see a format like this:

> €30.00

but I want this (italian format):

> €30,00

EDIT:
Ok the custom pipe,but as you can see in the documentation 
[CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)
and in the browser support
[Browser support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support),
this pipe uses the Internationalization API so it should be in the correct locale ID (I am using Chrome latest)

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858634/angular2-currency-pipe-change-decimal-separator

Comment: Ok but my browser is in `it`, why I need to create a custom pipe, why the standard pipe doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can set the locale-id which you could add  to the providers

```
 providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE'}],
```

and then,

in template

```
 <h2>Price:<h2>
 {{price|currency:'EUR':true}}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/VwahNIZh3KLjRTqYtyMk?p=preview)**

Comment: Ok it works but How to set it dinamically, based on the browserl language?

Comment: Yes you can do that based on route parames or  you should use translation i8 library

Comment: How to put translations in `providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE'}]`

Comment: You can set the values like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2/45624434#45624434

Comment: did the answer help ?

Comment: I want to understand why this pipe don't internationalize correctly the currency like described in the documentation