# Currency pipe parameter to obtain the format 000.000,00

Tags: angular, pipe, currency

I'm trying to use currency pipe to turn **123456.78** into **123.456,78**.

I want the dot to separate thousands and comma before decimal (italian currency format), but I can't find the correct combination of parameters.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ayl3pt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 Currency Pipe change decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858634/angular2-currency-pipe-change-decimal-separator)

Comment: @enno.void thank you, the second link solved the problem :)